# How to return the file path after saving a json file?

Tags: c++, qt

I can successfully save a json file i created and i know in which directory it is saved, but i want to display the file path to where it is being saved as a text display. I'm stuck on which Qt class and functions to use. Below is my save_json() function:

```
void EditWindow::save_json()
{
    // update Plot vector
    for(size_t i = 0; i < plots.size(); i++)  {
        //update json object
        if(plots[i]->save_changes())  {
              // reload_nodes(i);
        }
    }

    /* Update json file
     *
     */
    cout<<"Json filename" <<jsonfile<<endl;
    QFile saveFile(QString::fromStdString(jsonfile));
    if (!saveFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))  {

        qWarning("Couldn't open save file.");

    }

    QJsonArray plotsArray;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < plots.size(); i++){
        plotsArray.append(plots[i]->get_json_val());
    }

    QJsonDocument saveDoc(plotsArray);
    saveFile.write(saveDoc.toJson());
    setup_plot_list();
    cout<<"JSON FILE SAVED"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: 1. Where is _jsonfile_ defined? 2. Would you like to display only the path or the path with the file name? 3. Where should the text be displayed? Also, I don't think it is a good idea to return the path, but to set it, i.e. instead of _QString saveJson()_ - _void saveJson(const QString fileName)_. Furthermore, if the file cannot be written, you proceed with the writing anyway.

Comment: 1. jsonfile is defined in the header file
2. Only the path
3. Text should be displayed on a GUI just like how you'd normally display text with QLabel such as text->setText("path");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that _std::string jsonfile and *QLabel *text* are members of *EditWindow*, use [QFileInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html) to do something like this:

```
...
jsonfile.assign(...); // this is where you set the value of jsonfile
QFileInfo fi(QString::fromStdString(jsonfile));
text->setText(fi.path());
...
```

That should do the work, but you could experiment with different methods of *QFileInfo* in order to display different information.

Comment: Wasn't sure why .path() was displaying a period ( . ) instead of the path but i used .absoluteFilePath() to display the path and file name and it works now. Thank you!